# Regex for xx.xxx

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a bunch of codes and I need a regex that will match against xx.xxx in any string. Example 'xx.xxx', 'Something-xx.xxx'  Note: These are not numbers they are X letter characters.

A bunch of regex but I'm having trouble getting it right

Comment: Are you looking for literal `xx-xxx`, or do you mean word characters or letters in a pattern `xx-xxx` (e.g. `ab-cde`, `aa-bbb`, etc.)? Please provide an example of what you expected to work instead of just asking for a solution.

Comment: Probably need a bit more information. What other characters are valid (outside of 'xx.xxx')? Is 'xx.xxx-Something' valid? What about 'Somethingxx.xxx'?

Comment: From the post - " Note: These are not numbers they are X letter characters." and it's xx.xxx, no dash.   Example 'xx.xxx', 'Something-xx.xxx' then it matches / is valid

Comment: There is no reason for a regex in this. You want `str.includes('xx.xxx')`. See [`String.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

Comment: Still on what Phill said in the comment above, why not a simple `String.prototype.indexOf()`? Unlike `includes`, it works on IE (if someone still cares about IE...)

Comment: @Phil @Gerardo, I agree, i was directed to use a regex for this as it might change.  I went with `/x{2,}\.x{3,}/ `.   Is it faster to use a regex for this case?  Not sure why but I didn't want to ask either :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for exactly 'xx.xxx', then `/xx\.xxx/` would do the trick, where the `\` is an escape for `.`, which without an escape, will match on any character. If you want a variable number of 'x's you can make it a bit dynamic with something like `/x{2,}\.x{3,}/` for 2 or more 'x's match prior to the `.` and 3 or more matched after.

Comment: I tried 
  ```const sensitiveCode = /x{2,}\.{3,}/;
    if(sensitiveCode.test('xx.xxx')){
      console.log('running');
      console.log('running');
      console.log('running');
      console.log('running');
    }```
But it didn't work

Comment: @Rob your regex does not match the one in this answer

Answer (score 0):

Well, going purely off your problem description (I'm not sure why you require a regex), something like this will work:

`/.*xx\.xxx/`

This will look for any string containing `xx.xxx` with an optional prefix of any characters. If you also want to allow for characters after your code, change it to this instead:

`/.*xx\.xxx.*/`

Comment: JavaScript regex does not require a pattern spanning the entire string to match like Java does